# How to create Facebook RTSP stream with C# .NET Core (windows + linux) using Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rtsp

Connection i need is:

`React Native Application -> C# .Net Core Server -> RTSP Facebook API`

To be honest, i am not sure how to start with that. My first idea was to use GRPC Streams as connector between Client and Server, and then convert everything to RTSP at Server and send it to Facebook API. First problem i have found there are not many "fresh" libraries or SDKs for .Net Core allows me to make server side stream via RTSP.

Have you any idea how to cope with that?